# Office365 Sharepoint social.feed AAD Authorization

Tags: azure, api, sharepoint, ms-office

I'm currently testing RESTfull API access to Office365 Sharepoint server using bearer authentication (oAuth2).
I can succesfully get current files in the OneDrive via the /_api/web endpoint but get System.UnauthorizedAccessException on all _/api/social.feed endpoints.

I granted all available Sharepoint rights in AAD to the (test) application, just to be on the safe side, the token says: [scp] => MyFiles.Write MyFiles.Read AllSites.FullControl AllSites.Manage AllSites.Write AllSites.Read

The exact same endpoint is accessible and returns a sane result when accessed through a browser with "normal" fedAuth/rtFa authentication cookies (aka normal browser login) for the same user.

What am I doing wrong to retrieve the social.feed(/my/feed) for the access_token I'm presenting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Office 365 APIs do not support the permission to use the REST or CSOM APIs with the bearer authentication against anything the Web/Mobile App cannot ask consent for from the User launching the app. The social feeds are not included, the latest blog posts explains the current support http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/
If you feel this is important please submit your feedback to UserVoice where our engineers are looking at http://aka.ms/OfficeDevFeedback

Comment: Thx Jeremy, you exactly answered my question and removed any doubt I had about this issue. I've been mailing support about this issue for three weeks and they still have come up with this answer. Thx!
And yes, the social API is of extreme importance to us, alas!