# Office 365 Social APIs Access Denied

Tags: android, sharepoint-2013, office365, adal

I am working with Office 365 and the Sharepoint 2013 APIs.  I am using Azure AD to authenticate a user and have a test application setup inside AAD that has all the delegated permissions set to enabled in the configure tab for Sharepoint 2013. I am making these calls from a native android application and have been able to successfully authenticate with Microsoft's ADAL(ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationLibrary) using this oauth authority url: https://login.windows.net//oauth2/token?api-version=1.0.  I then access my test share point site and get back a list with https:////_api/Web/Lists?getByTitle('')/Items using the Oauth token that I received from back from using ADAL. That all works well and fine, but when I try to access the Social APIs with the same token process I get a 401 Unauthorized.  The url that I am using to get the current users information is: https:////_api/social.following/my.  What am I doing wrong that is causing the lists api work and the social api to fail? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you requesting a new token for the resource before calling that resource?

The ADAL library must acquire a new Access token for each resource you are requesting. Our library automatically does the redemption of the refresh token for the new Access token if you call **acquireToken()** using the new resource endpoint. This is hinted at in the API docuemtation.

Example:

```
mAuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(ToDoActivity.this, Constants.AUTHORITY_URL,
                false);
mAuthContext.acquireToken(activity, resource, clientId, redirectUri, loginHint, prompt, extraQueryParameters, callback)

//do work with the token
// now get token for new_resource

mAuthContext.acquireToken(activity, new_resource, clientId, redirectUri, loginHint, prompt, extraQueryParameters, callback)
```

You can use an example here which will help you see how this can be done: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Android

Comment: I am not changing my resource so there isn't a need to get a new token.  I am trying to access the social API's for the same resource and am getting the 401 unauthorized.  I have found information that as of right now the social API's are not currently supported on native mobile applications. The link to this information is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272399/office365-sharepoint-social-feed-aad-authorization.